# Water still circulating through toilet even after I shut off the water supply!

Tags: plumbing, water, leak, toilet

[Full youtube video is here.](https://youtu.be/JrgMbDHG39s)

Basically when I turn all the water off to my toilet, water is still leaking out of a yellow tub from inside the tank, and circulating through the toilet.

I need to fix this so that water is not leaking and so when I turn the water off, no more water gets circulated through the toilet. Any ideas as to what is going wrong and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the shutoff valve (the first thing you showed in the video, near the floor) is not 100% shutting off the water. Hard water can cause this as deposits inside the valve can prevent the gate from fully shutting.

You could either replace the valve stem (can be done without shutting off hour house supply) or replace the shutoff valve entirely. I generally prefer replacing the entire shutoff valve with ball valves rather than gate valves, because I find they last longer and are easier to operate.

Here's an example of the kind I like to use: [Ball shutoff valve example](http://www.supplyhouse.com/Brasscraft-KTCR19X-C-5-8-OD-Compr-x-3-8-OD-Compr-1-4-Turn-Angle-Ball-Stop-Lead-Free-Chrome-Plated?gclid=CLGLocDP5c8CFdKFfgodvx4Kcg)

Comment: Even ball valves can be blocked by scale, rust and or small rocks but can usually be cleared with several openings and closings. If it is a washer based shutoff the washer needs to be replaced and that requires the water to be turned off the valve taken apart and a new 3 cent washer installed, would be a plus if this was not missed.

Comment: Thanks @Sean (+1) - quick question: later in the video I show a yellow tub on the inside of my tank. I see water actively running out of it - is that normal? Or might that need replacing as well? Thanks again!